# Calling Page from Class

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, class, static-methods

I have this code to display a javascript message alert box from my server,it works fine but now i want to move the entire code into one static class so that i can call it from anywhere in my application without having to copy the code again to that page, this is the function i use right now:

```
private static void MessageBox(string msg)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine + "window.alert('" + msg + "')</script>";
    Page.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Now i want to be able to call this function from a static class on any webform i create in my application.

This is the error i get underlined on "Page.Control.Add(lbl)":
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code-behind `Page` is a property of type `Page` (confusing I know!) so it refers to an instance of the `Page` class. To your static method outside of this scope it only know of the class `Page` and so the compiler sees you attempting to call a static property called `Controls` which doesn't exist on the `Page` class and so throws an error your way.

You will need to pass the `Page` instance to the `MessageBox` method:

```
public static void MessageBox(Page page, string msg)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine + "window.alert('" + msg + "')</script>";
    page.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, honestly i dunno where i would be without stackoverflow :)